# Update only ForeignKey reference when given nested object

Tags: angularjs, django, nested, django-rest-framework, serialization

I was stuck for a while on what I thought should be a simple pattern.  So I'll share here how I resolved it for others who run into the same thing.  Maybe some will suggest better solutions too.

Using Django Rest Framework for the API and Angular 1.5 for the front end.

### Challenge:

Include detailed (nested) information about a person's household along with the person record to avoid an extra network round-trip, and be able to change household the person belongs to.

By default, DRF is happy to provide the nested information from the related model. But it's not so happy to take it back if you change any of it.

Angular is happy to display nested information of a resource, but its default action is to send back all of the resources data in exactly the same nested format when updating.

Here's the DRF setup that doesn't quite work:

```python
# Models
class Household(models.Model):
    full_address = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, default='')

class Person(models.Model):
    household=models.ForeignKey(
        'household.Household',
        null=True,
        related_name="persons",)
    full_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)


# Views
class HouseholdViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    model = Household
    queryset = Household.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HouseholdSerializer

class PersonViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    model = Person
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer


# Serializers
class HouseholdSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Household


class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    household = HouseholdSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id', 'household', 'full_name', )
```

When angular gets the person resource, the household id and full address are nested such that "household" is now an object instead of a primary key.

```json
{
    "id": 42,
    "full_name": "Lisa Adams",
    "household": {
        "id": 17,
        "full_address": "123 Main st, Springfield, ST, 55555"
    }
}
```

When the Lisa leaves home and moves in with her new roommate at a different household, the user changes the household to a different existing address and angular sends a PUT request. Success is indicated by the server 200 response, but the new household is not persisted to the database. So if the user looks at the person record again, it still has the old household.

This is a result of the household field being set to read_only in the person serializer. DRF ignores the nested object silently.

But if that's changed to read_only=False, DRF insists that an explicit .update() must be included.

```sh
AssertionError: The `.update()` method does not support writable
nestedfields by default. Write an explicit `.update()` method for serializer
```

I worked at writing a custom update function for a while and couldn't get it to work. I didn't need to update anything in the nested information.  I just needed to change the reference to a different household record.  All of the examples seemed more complicated than needed and I never got the custom update() to work for this simple use case.

Surely updating the reference to the foreign record is a common thing, even when the details from that record are present. But I didn't find any officially documented example and I just persisted in missing one detail or another for hours while trying to modify examples on SO and blogs.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

Since DRF was happy to take a changed reference to the "household" if it didn't have any nested details, I worked around the problem of updating it by leaving the "household" field intact as just a primary key. Then I added a new field "household_details" to the PersonSerializer to provide the details in a new namespace.

```python
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    household_details = HouseholdSerializer(many=False, read_only=True, source='household')
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id', 'household', 'household_details', 'full_name',)
```

This creates a new field point at the same "household" model, but since it's read_only, DRF will ignore it when submitted back by angular.

Then I just had to complicate my angular controller a little to read from the "household_details" field and write to the "household" field with the id field from the "household_details" when updating.

```html
<household-small-card household="person.household_detail"></household-small-card>
```

```javascript
function update(new_household_detail) {
  vm.person.household = new_household_detail.id;
  vm.person.$update(function () {
    toastr.success('Updated ' + vm.person.full_name + ' Successfully');
  }, function (errorResponse) {
    toastr.error('Failed:  ' + errorResponse.data.message);
  });
}
```

*Note: This code is all simplified from my working code.  I didn't confirm that it works. But the concepts should be clearer here. Writing it up in this format helps me solidify the solution in my mind. I hope it helps someone else to have it here.*

Answer (score 0):

**An Inverse Alternative** to @shanemgrey:

Instead of appending `_detail` to your main object, (which is nasty IMO), you can flip the fields around.  Use `household_id` as your ID field, and keep `household` as your object field:

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    household = HouseholdSerializer(read_only=True)
    household_id = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id', 'household', 'household_id', 'full_name',)
```

DRF will automatically link `household_id` from your JSON to the object, so you don't have to do anything else.

Comment: Didn't know about the automatic link.  Thanks!