# Django Rest Framework: Create Related Object or Find by ID

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**Problem**

We are developing an API using DRF to create a Membership record that includes a related Entity record w/ all the personal information and a related Address record w/ all the address information.

On this API we want to include behavior in way that allows the API to receive an Entity ID to reuse an existing entity or all the other attributes of the entity to create a new one. The same goes for the address.

When we post all the required information, with the goal of creating the related Entity and Address, everything works fine, but when we just post the IDs we are facing a problem.

The issue we are facing is that if we send the ID w/o all the other related fields we are getting validator errors and we cannot proceed with the get of the related objects and create main record.

**What we have tried**

What we have done so far is:

1. Created the Serializers for Membership, Entity and Address.
2. Configured the Serializer for Membership to have the related Entity and Address serializers.
3. Overwritten the .create method on the Membership serializer to create the nested objects.

The closest problem / answer we could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285305/update-only-foreignkey-reference-when-given-nested-object), but in fact we need our related serializers to be writable and it seems like in this case the solution will not work.

**What we would Expect**

What we would expect to do here is intercept the behavior of the DRF and be able to tell it that when the ID is present we could ignore serialization or use the ID field o retrieve the object from the database if necessary.

We need to keep the serializer writable to allow these objects to be created if necessary.

**Our Code**

```
class CoreMembership(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    entity = CoreEntitySerializer(read_only=False, many=False, allow_null=True)
    address = CoreAddressSerializer(read_only=False, many=False, allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Membership
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        address = validated_data.pop('address')
        entity = validated_data.pop('entity')
        
        (...)

        return membership

class MstEntitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Entity
        fields = '__all__'

class MstAddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = '__all__'
```